# apt-get update Bad header line

Tags: apt-get

I'm hosting a reprepo debian package server with a bunch of arm packages for an embedded linux project. I have arm symbol files in the repo. On my host machine, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I want to -force-architecture install them. When I update my PPAs with my debian repo `apt-get update` is erroring with `Bad header line`. I've been searching for hours for a solution. Can't even find a way to turn on verbose for apt-get. dpkg has --debug= so I tried `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--debug=3773" update` with no success.

Checked /var/log/dpkg.log and /etc/apt/*.logs nothing in them... How do you debug apt-get?

Comment: When I got to the URL that it is querying I can see all the info headers for all the pkgs.

Comment: I've also tried `sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true`

Comment: I've have similar issue, how did you solve this ?

Comment: I didn't. Ended up making the packages arch all.

Comment: Had a similar issue on Ubuntu Trusty that ended up being a TLS issue (worked fine using HTTP instead of HTTPS) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227190/ubuntu-trusty-err-https-dl-yarnpkg-com-stable-main-amd64-packages-bad-header-l